# One interface per table/class asp.net webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, asp.net-web-api, solid-principles

I just wanna ask. Is it OK to create one `interface` per `table` or `class` like this:

```
public interface ICustomer{
   long id;
   string firstname;
   string lastname;
}

 [Table("Customer")]
 public class Customer : ICustomer{
       public long id {get;set;}
       //implementation etc...
    }


public interface ICustomerDetails{
   long id;
   bool isMarried;
   string billingAddress;
}


[Table("CustomerDetails")]
public class CustomerDetails : ICustomerDetails{
   [Key]
   public long id {get;set;}
   //implementation etc...
}
```

I want to apply **DI** principle and I have 50 tables right now. I'm going to follow the **SOLID** principle. This is existing project. I'm newbie in OOP and trying to learn this principle

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Why do you expect this to be a benefit in your project?

Comment: I don't expect anything yet. Is this a bad practice? I'm new with this. Please enlighten me.

Comment: This seems to violate the KISS principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about WHY you want to do this, it's hard to give more details. However, based on what you've provided in your question, the short answer is NO. You wouldn't normally inject objects like these (entities).

Typically, you'd inject a service, or a repository, or something that has functionality (methods), because that functionality will need to be different in unit tests (you don't want to actually do anything with a database in a unit test, for example).

If you want to instantiate a customer, then just do that. No need to inject it. For example (this is more MVC than WebApi, but the principle is the same):

```
 public class Customer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    List<Customer> GetCustomers();
    Customer GetCustomer(long id);
    void SaveCustomer(Customer customer);
}

public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        // something here to retrieve the list of customers from a database 
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer(long id)
    {
        // something here to retrieve the specific customer from a database
    }

    public void SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        // save the customer
    }
}
```

Then you would inject the repository into your controller:

```
 public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
    public CustomerController(ICustomerRepository repository)
    {
        _customerRepository = repository;
    }
    // GET: Customer
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var customers = _customerRepository.GetCustomers();
        // typically, here you would map the customers to a viewmodel, but for the sake of brevity...
        return View(customers);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        // there are better ways to do this (look at model binding), but as an example:
        var customer = new Customer();
        customer.Id = collection["id"];
        customer.FirstName = collection["firstname"];
        customer.LastName = collection["lastname"];

        _customerRepository.SaveCustomer(customer);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

If this isn't what you were going for, perhaps you can provide more detail in your question and get a better idea of how to accomplish your goals. But if you just want to experiment with Dependency Injection, this should suffice. So, there's no need for the interfaces you've created (ICustomerDetails and ICustomer).

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for explanation @Matt M. I'm gonna follow that!

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't going to be injecting all kinds of different "tables" or entities that are changing or is some kind of plugin architecture, then I do not know why *every* class needs to have an Interface.  It seems like you are making extra work for yourself for some unknown reason.  It is the You Aren't Going to Need It.  If you do not know why you need them, and you have 50 of them, then I'd be hesitant to do it.

Now if you know that you will have different CustomerDetails that you need to inject somewhere maybe in a constructor for whatever reason, then make it, but other than that, no.  Let the framework do what you need and when it complains or it becomes very hard to work with fix it.